# SQL join with default fallback

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table called `movies` containing two columns, `description` and `longer_description`. These columns contain translation keys that are to be used for fetching translations. I managed to fetch the translations by using joins, but I want to fallback to a default locale if no translations are found.

I have a database structure like this:

**Movies table**

```
movies
---------------------------------------
name | description | longer_description
```

**Localizations table**

```
localizations 
------------------------------
textkey | locale | translation
```

with textkey + locale working as a primary key.

Example data for movies:

```
name         | description        | longer_description
-------------------------------------------------------------
Batman movie | batman.description | batman.longer_description
```

These values are used to match the textkey in localizations table:

Example data for localizations:

```
textkey                   | locale | translation
---------------------------------------------------------------
batman.description        | en     | english description
batman.longer_description | en     | english longer description
```

What I want to achieve is making a query with given textkey + locale, and if a translation exists: select, and if not: fallback to default `en` locale.

```
SELECT
    m.name,
    t1.translation AS description,
    t2.translation AS long_description
FROM
    movies m
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    localizations t1
ON
    t1.language = 'sv' AND
    t1.text_key = m.description
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    localizations t2
ON
    t2.language = 'sv' AND
    t2.text_key = m.long_description
ORDER BY
    m.name
```

This will get me the translations I want, but it will not solve the case where a translation doesn't exist and I need to fallback on the `en` locale.

Comment: It would be yet another join like `... left outer join localizations t3 on (t3.language = 'en' and t3.text_key = m.description) ...` and in the `select` clause `... coalesce(t1.translation, t3.translation) as description, ...`. Same for `long_description`. However it would be nice to store the default (English) text in the `movies` table instead of `localizations` so it is not requires the ambiguous joins.

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto, this works. But I agree with you, the defaults should be stored in the `movies` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stored function for that:

```
create function fn_get_translation(p_key text, p_language text) returns text static strict language sql as $$
  select
    translation
  from
    localizations l join 
      (values(1,p_language),(2,'en')) as lng(ord,code) on (l.locale = lng.code)
  where
    l.text_key = p_key
  order by
    lng.ord
  limit 1
$$;
```

Disclaimer: function not tested but i believe that you will be able to fix the possible errors.

And after that the query will be more simple:

```
select
  m.name,
  fn_get_translation(m.description, 'sv') as description,
  fn_get_translation(m.long_description, 'sv') as long_description
from
  movies m;
```

Comment: This looks much much more cleaner and worked after some minor adjustments. Many thanks, appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

You could just change the select portion of your statement and include 'case'. This will then use the en locale when a translation is not found.

```
SELECT
     m.name,
     case when t1.translation is null then m.description else t1.translation end AS description,
     case when t2.translation is null then m.longer_description else t2.translation end AS long_description
FROM 
    movies m
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    localizations t1
ON
    t1.language = 'sv' AND
    t1.text_key = m.description
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    localizations t2
ON
    t2.language = 'sv' AND
    t2.text_key = m.long_description
ORDER BY
    m.name
```

Comment: `case when t1.translation is null then m.description else t1.translation end AS description` is equal to `coalesce(t1.translation, m.description) AS description` BTW.

Comment: This will only set the `description` and `longer_description` to the text keys and not the actual translations for the `en` locale. @WilliamAllenMAPMECHANICS

Comment: @Abelisto - Oh yeah! That would be easier.