# Optimize PostgreSQL query with slow and bad estimate on Function Scan and Nested Loop

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with 4 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE definition (
   id                bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
   public_id         uuid UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
   name              varchar(128) NOT NULL,
   type              definition_type NOT NULL,
   created_at        timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
   updated_at        timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
   created_by_token  varchar(128) NOT NULL CHECK (created_by_token <> ''),
   created_by_user   varchar(128)
);

CREATE INDEX ON definition (type);
CREATE INDEX ON definition (created_at);
CREATE INDEX ON definition (updated_at);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_definition_name ON definition (name);
CREATE INDEX definition_lower_token_idx ON definition (lower(created_by_token));
CREATE INDEX definition_lower_user_idx ON definition (lower(created_by_user));

CREATE TABLE definition_translation (
   id             bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
   language       varchar(35) NOT NULL,
   definition_id  uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES definition(public_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   created_at     timestamptz NOT NULL
   updated_at     timestamptz NOT NULL
   title          varchar(64) NOT NULL CHECK (title <> ''),
   template       text NOT NULL CHECK (template <> ''),
   redirect_to    text
);

ALTER TABLE definition_translation
   ADD CONSTRAINT unique_translation_by_definition_per_language UNIQUE (definition_id, language);

CREATE INDEX ON definition_translation (language);
CREATE INDEX ON definition_translation (definition_id);
CREATE INDEX ON definition_translation (created_at);
CREATE INDEX ON definition_translation (updated_at);

CREATE INDEX ON definition_translation USING gin (title gin_trgm_ops);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_definition_translation(did uuid, lang varchar, default_lang varchar)
   RETURNS TABLE (
      title       varchar(64),
      template    text,
      redirect_to text
   ) AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
      SELECT dt.title, dt.template, dt.redirect_to
      FROM definition_translation dt JOIN
         (values(1,lang),(2,default_lang)) AS lng(ord,code) ON (dt.language = lng.code)
      WHERE dt.definition_id = did
      ORDER BY lng.ord
      LIMIT 1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TABLE broadcast (
   id                bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
   public_id         uuid UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
   definition_id     uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES definition(public_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   created_at        timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
   begin_at          timestamptz NOT NULL,
   expire_at         timestamptz,
   created_by_token  varchar(128) NOT NULL CHECK (created_by_token <> ''),
   created_by_user   varchar(128),
   replace_values    jsonb
);

ALTER TABLE broadcast
   ADD CONSTRAINT unique_broadcast_by_definition UNIQUE (definition_id);

CREATE INDEX ON broadcast (created_at);
CREATE INDEX ON broadcast (begin_at);
CREATE INDEX ON broadcast (expire_at);
CREATE INDEX broadcast_lower_token_idx ON broadcast (lower(created_by_token));
CREATE INDEX broadcast_lower_user_idx ON broadcast (lower(created_by_user));

CREATE TABLE broadcast_acknowledgement (
   id             bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
   public_id      uuid UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
   broadcast_id   uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES broadcast(public_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   account        citext NOT NULL,
   created_at     timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
);

ALTER TABLE broadcast_acknowledgement
   ADD CONSTRAINT unique_ack_by_broadcast_per_account UNIQUE (broadcast_id, account);

CREATE INDEX ON broadcast_acknowledgement (account);
CREATE INDEX ON broadcast_acknowledgement (created_at);
```

The rationale behind this database schemas is to avoid having to create a broadcast row for each user account (milions of them), but instead, have a separate `broadcast_acknowledgement` table that store the acknowledgement for each account by broadcast.

The `get_definition_translation` function is inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018977/4709839
Each broadcast has a "model" stored in the `definition` table, and each definition can have one or more translations `definition_translation`.

I use this query to fetch all the broadcasts that are not acknowledged by an account. The query joins the definition type of the broadcast and localized columns `title` and `template` of the definition using a primary language and a fallback in case no translation exists for the primary language.

```
WITH acknowledged AS (
    SELECT ba.broadcast_id 
    FROM broadcast_acknowledgement AS ba
    WHERE ba.account = 'toto'
) SELECT
    d.type,
    dt.title,
    dt.template,
    COALESCE(dt.redirect_to, '') AS redirect_to,
    src.replace_values,
    src.begin_at,
    'broadcast:' || src.public_id AS id
  FROM broadcast AS src
  JOIN definition AS d ON src.definition_id = d.public_id, get_definition_translation(d.public_id , 'fr_FR', 'en_US') AS dt
  WHERE (src.public_id NOT IN (SELECT broadcast_id FROM acknowledged)
    AND src.begin_at <= current_timestamp
    AND src.expire_at > current_timestamp);
```

The query use a view to fetch all the broadcasts acknowledged by an account and use the rows to filter the selected broadcasts in the main query.
In the JOIN clause, the `get_definition_translation` is responsible for returning the translation of the definition that is referenced by the broadcast. It takes a primary and fallback value for the language.

The query plan looks like:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=851.39..7815.32 rows=250000 width=149) (actual time=1.400..12.740 rows=288 loops=1)
   Output: d.type, dt.title, dt.template, COALESCE(dt.redirect_to, ''::text), src.replace_values, src.begin_at, ('broadcast:'::text || (src.public_id)::text)
   CTE acknowledged
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.broadcast_acknowledgement ba  (cost=6.18..823.06 rows=209 width=16) (actual time=0.159..0.495 rows=212 loops=1)
           Output: ba.broadcast_id
           Recheck Cond: (ba.account = 'toto'::citext)
           Heap Blocks: exact=210
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on broadcast_acknowledgement_account_idx  (cost=0.00..6.13 rows=209 width=0) (actual time=0.136..0.136 rows=212 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (ba.account = 'toto'::citext)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=28.08..117.01 rows=250 width=53) (actual time=1.284..3.521 rows=288 loops=1)
         Output: src.replace_values, src.begin_at, src.public_id, d.type, d.public_id
         Hash Cond: (d.public_id = src.definition_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on public.definition d  (cost=0.00..77.04 rows=2504 width=20) (actual time=0.010..1.054 rows=2504 loops=1)
               Output: d.id, d.public_id, d.name, d.type, d.created_at, d.updated_at, d.created_by_token, d.created_by_user
         ->  Hash  (cost=24.95..24.95 rows=250 width=49) (actual time=1.253..1.253 rows=288 loops=1)
               Output: src.replace_values, src.begin_at, src.public_id, src.definition_id
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 33kB
               ->  Seq Scan on public.broadcast src  (cost=4.70..24.95 rows=250 width=49) (actual time=0.834..1.098 rows=288 loops=1)
                     Output: src.replace_values, src.begin_at, src.public_id, src.definition_id
                     Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) AND (src.begin_at <= now()) AND (src.expire_at > now()))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 212
                     SubPlan 2
                       ->  CTE Scan on acknowledged  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=209 width=16) (actual time=0.162..0.702 rows=212 loops=1)
                             Output: acknowledged.broadcast_id
   ->  Function Scan on public.get_definition_translation dt  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=96) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=1 loops=288)
         Output: dt.title, dt.template, dt.redirect_to
         Function Call: get_definition_translation(d.public_id, 'fr_FR'::character varying, 'en_US'::character varying)
 Planning time: 0.621 ms
 Execution time: 12.946 ms
(29 rows)
```

The database was populated with randomly generated data to test the performances of the query.

```
root=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM broadcast;
 count 
-------
   500
(1 row)

root=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM broadcast_acknowledgement;
  count   
----------
 15306826
(1 row)

root=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM definition;
 count 
-------
  2504
(1 row)

root=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM definition_translation;
 count 
-------
 47469
(1 row)
```

I would like to optimize the query to reduce the time taken by the Nested Loop and Function Scan. I cannot figure why the query planner has a bad rows count estimate for those two parts as well, and wonder if this is impacting performances.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `language plpgsql`, but turn it into `language sql stable` then the function isn't a black box to the optimizer any more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The misestimate is a consequence of the fact that functions are “black boxes” for the PostgreSQL optimizer (from PostgreSQL 12 on, the new feature "support functions" can mitigate that, but that requires writing C code).

To get a better estimate, tell the optimizer how many rows the function normally returns, so that it doesn't have to use its guessed number of 1000:

```
ALTER FUNCTION get_definition_translation(did uuid, lang varchar, default_lang varchar)
ROWS 1;
```

You'd be much better off if you didn't use a function, but substitute the actual query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't knew about this possibility. It solves the misestimate in the query plan. Regarding the function itself, I was strugling to implements a JOIN fallback on the definition translation language before I found this function that I adapted. Could you provide a some guidance about the function internal query substitution into the main query, or another way to have a fallback on the JOIN ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What I need is to join dt.title and dt.template to the row based on the `language` column of the translation. If no row for this definiton/language exists, it should try to join with another language predicate. I don't see where to use the `EXISTS(..) clause you mention.`

Comment: Scratch that, I misread the query. That should be `CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ...)`.

Comment: @Launrenz Albe Performance improvement isn't that huge, but it's always good to take. thanks.

Comment: This statement is no longer true since PG 12: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/optimizer-support-functions/

Comment: @felixfbecker Thanks, yes, I wrote that article. I have added a mention to the answer.

Comment: An alternative would be to turn the function into a `language sql` function marked as `stable`, then Postgres can inline it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, if your query satisfies the [necessary conditions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions#Inlining_conditions_for_table_functions).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: which the one in the question satisfies

Answer (score 0):

just one point: CTEs are optimization fences in postgres: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/. Do you get the same performance when you inline the CTE?

Comment: Yes I tried it, and found no notable performance differences.